# x86 Register Values

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86, x86-64

Given the following x86-64 AT&T assembly line:

`cmpl   $0x7,0xc(%rsp)`

This is accessing the 12th offset from $rsp in memory. So is it accessing `12*4 = 48`, 48th byte after `rsp` in memory or `12*8 = 96` 96th byte after `rsp`? Since this is 64-bit architecture, then a register would be 8 bytes long and therefore 96?

In any case, to access that position in `gdb`, would I do `x/96s $rsp`? Is there an easy way to just print that without the whole list of offsets?

If I write `x/12s $rsp`, then I get memory addresses from `0x7FFFFFFFE1F0` to `0x7FFFFFFFE20D`. So the offset difference between start and end is 29 bytes. How is that logical, when I specified 12?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offset within assembly is a byte offset, so that instruction is looking at the data 12 bytes above `rsp`. This is because x86 allows access to any address, except in the case of SSE instructions, some of which require 16 byte alignment.

In gdb, the number after the `/` indicates how many pieces of data you want to see, not an offset. If you want to offset the register, you need to add it to the location. Also, you are seeing 30 bytes because you are using the `s` type specifier, which means gdb is showing you a null-terminated string. To see data, you will want to use a different format. Some options are: `o` (octal), `x` (hexadecimal), `d` (decimal), `t` (binary), and `i` (instruction). (Use `help x` to see the full list). You also should specify the size of data you want to see for any of the numeric types. Use `b` (byte), `h` (2 bytes), `w` (4 bytes), or `g` (8 bytes).

For example, if you want to see 2 4-byte words starting 12 bytes after `rsp`, and have them shown in hexadecimal, you would use:

```
x/2wx $rsp + 12
```

Comment: IIrc, `cmpl` instruction is for 32-bit wide values (cmpb would be for a byte, cmpw for a 16-bit value), so I'm not surprised to see it using +3*4 as an offset ... it would use `cmpq` for a 64-bit value, wouldn't it ?